# Can we control the number of requests for API Load Testing?

Tags: locust

I have a list of tasks in locust file. I want to restrict the number of requests for every tasks.

class UserJourney(SequentialTaskSet):
counter = 1
request_limit = 1000

```
@task
def demo_get_test(self):
    if self.counter <= self.request_limit:
        self.client.get("/api/users?page=2", name='Users List')
    self.counter += 1
```

class DemoHttpUser(HttpUser):
host = "http://reqres.in"
tasks = [UserJourney]

I want to get the requests fired defined by me for task demo_get_test.

I tried using for loop and then calling event listener to stop test but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locust-plugins` has something like that a built-in feature, see https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/ccd679c5eba206fa6ce69c9ebccc5e4c2d93930e/examples/cmd_line_examples.sh#L12

You can check out the source code if you want to do it yourself in some other fashion: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/ccd679c5eba206fa6ce69c9ebccc5e4c2d93930e/locust_plugins/__init__.py#L171 (if you want to quit locust, call `runner.quit()`)

Firing event handlers does not control locust, their purpose it to provide you with an integration point for doing custom stuff when something (like stop/quit) is happening.

Comment: I have tried it. But if i put a iterations limit to 100 the number of requests after it is getting stopped is 98.

Comment: Combine it with —stop-timeout 10 (or a value at least as high as the time an iteration to take, to ensure every task gets to finish). That is probably your issue.

Comment: I tried stop timeout also. So the issue I am facing is when I run this command `locust -f locust/locust-load-test.py -u 10 -r 2 --headless --only-summary` with iteration count as 100, locust is ending the test at 98. I want to achieve the locust old feature --num-requests where we mention exact number of requests and test will end with that.